# avoid overlapping between line label and nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using tikz to draw a info flow diagram which contains a few long labels. What I get is unacceptably ugly, mainly resulting from various overlapping between labels and shapes. Ideally, I want the length of line segments dynamically harmonize with the length of texts over it. Is there a way to achieve so?

[image]

A minimal example is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{enc}=[circle, draw]
\tikzstyle{entity}=[rectangle, draw]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[enc] (app enc) {AEnc};
  \node[enc] (quote enc) [below = of app enc] {QEnc};
  \node[entity] (app) [right = of app enc] {app};
  \node[entity] (challenger) [right=of app] {Challenger};
  \draw[<->] (challenger) to 
      node[auto, swap]{1) $(n,c)$} 
      node[auto] {5) d} 
      (app);
  \draw[->] (app) to node[auto,swap] {2) $(n,c)$} (app enc);
  \draw[dashed,->] (app enc) to node[auto] {3) $appenc_{id} || n||r||CMAC(RK_{QE},.)$} (quote enc);
  \draw[dashed, ->] (quote enc) to node[auto] {4) $appenc_{id} || n||r||Sig_{EPID_{sk}}[.]$} (challenger);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can your longer labels have line breaks or do you want them to be kept in just one line?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for your comment. Well, I don't want them broken though I can shorten them by introducing more compact notations. But even short ones, like `1) (n,c)` between `app` and `challenger`, overlap with adjacent shapes.

Comment: The short answer is no you can't do that. Long answer yes maybe if you use the graphdrawing library with nontrivial adjustments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the distance between the nodes using `node distance` as an argument to the `tikzpicture` environment. Secondly, rather than using `auto` to place the node labels using `left=<dim>` and `right=<dim>` to manually move them into better positions.

[image]

I have also used `\DeclareMathOperator\appenc{\text{appenc}}` for your `appenc` as this looks bad above. You probably should do the same with `Sig` and perhaps others. My guess is that your notation can be improved, but it is easy to say this without knowing the full details:)

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareMathOperator\appenc{\text{appenc}}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{enc}=[circle, draw]
\tikzstyle{entity}=[rectangle, draw]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=25mm]
  \node[enc] (app enc) {AEnc};
  \node[enc] (quote enc) [below = of app enc] {QEnc};
  \node[entity] (app) [right = of app enc] {app};
  \node[entity] (challenger) [right=of app] {Challenger};
  \draw[<->] (challenger) to
      node[auto, swap]{1) $(n,c)$}
      node[auto] {5) d}
      (app);
  \draw[->] (app) to node[auto,swap] {2) $(n,c)$} (app enc);
  \draw[dashed,->] (app enc) to node[right=42mm] {3) $\appenc_{id} || n||r||CMAC(RK_{QE},.)$} (quote enc);
  \draw[dashed, ->] (quote enc) to node[left=38mm] {4) $\appenc_{id} || n||r||Sig_{EPID_{sk}}[.]$} (challenger);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no need for `node[right=42mm]` or `node[left=38mm]`, `node[left]` and `node[below right]` will do the job.

Comment: @Ignasi Not so: try it and you will see that the text overlaps the dotted lines.

Comment: Please, let me insist: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253462/1952

Comment: Andrew, I think the problem with your code comes from a little mistake. You define comment `3)` on a path between `app enc` and `quote enc`, while it *appears* right of a path between `quote enc` and `challenger`. And,of course, you need to fix the distance. Same with comment `4)`. If you attach to the correct path, you won't need touching distances.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but a long comment to [Andrew's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253246/1952). He uses `node[right=42mm]` or `node[left=38mm]` to manually adjust comment distance from comment to path between nodes. `TikZ` can do it for us with a correct `anchor` selection.

To place commen `3)` at left position of a path between `quote enc` and `app enc` nodes, the command is just

```
  \draw[dashed,->] (app enc) to node[left] {3) $\appenc_{id} || n||r||CMAC(RK_{QE},.)$} (quote enc);
```

and a similar one (with `below right` instead of `left`) can be used for the path between `quote enc` and `challenger` nodes.

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareMathOperator\appenc{\text{appenc}}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{enc}=[circle, draw]
\tikzstyle{entity}=[rectangle, draw]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=25mm]
  \node[enc] (app enc) {AEnc};
  \node[enc] (quote enc) [below = of app enc] {QEnc};
  \node[entity] (app) [right = of app enc] {app};
  \node[entity] (challenger) [right=of app] {Challenger};
  \draw[<->] (challenger) to
      node[auto, swap]{1) $(n,c)$}
      node[auto] {5) d}
      (app);
  \draw[->] (app) to node[auto,swap] {2) $(n,c)$} (app enc);
  \draw[dashed,->] (app enc) to node[left] {3) $\appenc_{id} || n||r||CMAC(RK_{QE},.)$} (quote enc);
  \draw[dashed, ->] (quote enc) to node[below right] {4) $\appenc_{id} || n||r||Sig_{EPID_{sk}}[.]$} (challenger);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and the result

[image]

Comment: OK, so now I am confused as when I tried this it didn't work... Indeed, I only added the manual adjustments to my answer because the text overlapped. I checked again that this "didn't work" after your comment. Yet now it works for me!? Anyway, +1 and thanks for the correction.

Comment: ...I suspect that I simply mixed up left and right

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\newcommand{\mi}[1]{\mathit{#1}}

\begin{document}\footnotesize 
\tikzstyle{enc}=[circle, draw]
\tikzstyle{entity}=[rectangle, draw]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm,>=latex']
  \node[enc] (app enc) {AEnc};
  \node[enc] (quote enc) [below = of app enc] {QEnc};
  \node[entity] (app) [right = of app enc] {app};
  \node[entity] (challenger) [right=of app] {Challenger};
  \draw[<->] (challenger) to 
      node[auto, swap]{1) $(n,c)$} 
      node[auto] {5) d} 
      (app);
  \draw[->] (app) to node[auto,swap] {2) $(n,c)$} (app enc);
  \draw[dashed,->] (app enc) to node[left,align=center] {3) $\textup{appenc}_{id} \left|| n||r|\right|$\\ $\times\mi{CMAC}(RK_{\mi{QE}},.)$} (quote enc);
  \draw[dashed, ->] (quote enc) to node[below right,align=center] {4) $\textup{appenc}_{id} || n||r||$ \\ $\times \textup{Sig}^{}_{\mi{EPID}_{sk}}[.]$} (challenger);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that doing things automatically here would be too difficult and may give ugly results. This is especially because you are using long formulas which cannot be easily broken. So, the only good-looking and less time-consuming solution would be manually breaking the formulas and sending the nodes more distance apart by the key `node distance= <length>` and adjust the text to smaller size (`\footnotesize`, for example, won't hurt). Also, leaving the `auto` option may not help in such cases. So, you can manually set `left`, `right`, `below right`, etc. for better placement of text and formulas.

Finally, I changed some multiple-character variables to `\textup` for clarity and some Capital-letters variables to `\mathit` also for better spacing.